LinkedIn post copies - text analysis tools
I want to use data from my work - 1000+ different copies with full meta data from LI. We've got a SaaS platform for brand's ambassadors, and give them a tool to create these copies and plan them. So the idea is to use this data to build a model, that could give some more insight in what creates the most reach in general.
The final goal is to create some sort of AI helper that could give hints to the writer on what and how to change the post so it will gain more reach long term. But my job would be to create a general model, that could analyze text based on the historical data. I'm not going to build an app for that. This project is for my Postgraduate Data Science diploma, so I'm in the process of learning all the tools necessary to build this kind of model.
And here lays the question I'm trying to answer - what tools, concepts or packages should I start learning in order to gain knowledge to create such a project? Sentiment analysis was my first guess, but from what I've found this will be only a small part of the whole idea. Which texts analysis tools would/could be applied in my case?
I'm not looking for the answers how to do it, just what knowledge I'm currently lacking. To get the foot inside the door, I need some more context.
Cheers
